# JasperReports: Getting JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser

Tags: java, maven-2, jasper-reports

We have created reports using *iReport4.5.1*. It is working properly in *iReport*.

After that we have integrated reports to our Application. We build our application using maven. Following is the *JasperReports* dependencies in *pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jasperreports-javaflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-javaflow</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and following is the *Java* code which generate the report :

```
String jrxmlFilePath = getConfigBundle().getString("jasper.templates.jrxml.path");
String jasperFilePath = getConfigBundle().getString("jasper.templates.jasper.path");
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlFilePath, jasperFilePath);
File jasperFile = new File(jasperFilePath);
Connection conn = setUpDataSource();
HashMap jasperParameter = setUpJasperParameterForPackingList(truckId, rackId, jasperFile);
JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFilePath, jasperParameter, conn);
ByteArrayOutputStream reportOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jprint, reportOutputStream);
return reportOutputStream;
```

When I call this code it will give me following error :

```
ERROR - [DGU_ACTION_SERVLET] ServletException
javax.servlet.ServletException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:535)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:433)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at com.saintgobain.dgu.mvc.action.DguActionServlet.process(DguActionServlet.java:41)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1342)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1318)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:207)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:172)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:108)
    at com.saintgobain.dgu.helper.ExportReportPDFHelper.printPackingListJasper(ExportReportPDFHelper.java:287)
    at com.saintgobain.dgu.helper.ExportReportPDFHelper.generatePDF4PackingList(ExportReportPDFHelper.java:353)
    at com.saintgobain.dgu.mvc.action.shipping.ExportShippingReportAction.execute(ExportShippingReportAction.java:79)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl.setProperty(XMLReaderImpl.java:266)
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setProperty(SAXParserImpl.java:183)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.configureParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:132)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:94)
    ... 32 more
ERROR - [DGU_ACTION_SERVLET] ServletException - root cause
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1342)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1318)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:207)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:172)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:108)
    at com.saintgobain.dgu.helper.ExportReportPDFHelper.printPackingListJasper(ExportReportPDFHelper.java:287)
    at com.saintgobain.dgu.helper.ExportReportPDFHelper.generatePDF4PackingList(ExportReportPDFHelper.java:353)
    at com.saintgobain.dgu.mvc.action.shipping.ExportShippingReportAction.execute(ExportShippingReportAction.java:79)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at com.saintgobain.dgu.mvc.action.DguActionServlet.process(DguActionServlet.java:41)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl.setProperty(XMLReaderImpl.java:266)
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setProperty(SAXParserImpl.java:183)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.configureParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:132)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:94)
    ... 32 more
```

1. we are using the both *iReport* and *JasperReports* version as 4.5.1
2. I have put the *XercesImpl.jar* (version 2.8.1) dependency in class path
3. we are using **Jdk.1.6.0_33**

Please help How do I remove this error?

Comment: we used 2.8.1 for Xerces.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using *Xerces*? It is from your statcktrace: `org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl.setProperty(XMLReaderImpl.java:266)`

Comment: We also have crimson dependency in pom.xml

Comment: It seems to me that the *crimson* is used as a *XML* parser in your case. And it doesn't support some features that are required for parsing *jrxml* file

Comment: The *iReport* is using *Xerces*

Comment: Do I need to give Xerces dependency in pom.xml? 
Have already given jasper dependancies and removed the crimson one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex its working . Thats the issues you had specified.

Comment: You are welcome :) I'll post this solution as an answer to help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from this line of the stacktrace:

```
org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl.setProperty(XMLReaderImpl.java:266)
```

the [*Crimson*](http://xml.apache.org/crimson/) *XML* parser is used in your application.

The *Crimson* implementation does not support property value different from those values<sup><sup>[1]</sup></sup>:

```
"http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler"
```

and

```
"http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler"
```

but the *JasperReports* engine try to use ***`http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage`*** property (as you can see from the stacktrace<sup><sup>[2]</sup></sup>).

The *iReport* is using the [*Xerces*](http://xerces.apache.org/) *XML* parser implementation. For example, the *iReport 4.7.0* and *iReport 5.2.0* are using the *2.8.0* version of *Xerces*.

You can try to add this (*Xerces*) library to the *pom.xml* as dependency.

*Notes*:

<sub><sup>[1]: See the source code of method `getProperty(String)` in *org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl* class</sup></sub>.

<sub><sup>[2]:The *JR* engine try to set this property for *SAXParser* in *`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.configureParser(SAXParser)`* method</sup></sub>.