# Error creating SAX parser JasperReports on Java Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReports in order to create a reports on an Java web application using tomcat, but I am facing this error which I was not able to quite find a solution on Google. The only topics that I found talked about to add Xerces to the dependencys which I have done but still not changed a thing.

```
String reportOutput = reportOutputLocation+reportName;
InputStream reportTemplate = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportSrcLocation);
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportTemplate);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
Map<String, Object> paramObjects = new HashMap<String, Object>();
paramObjects.putAll(parameters);
JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, paramObjects, conn);
```

The error happens over here: `JRXmlLoader.load(reportTemplate);`

This is the stack trace output:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.BaseSaxParserFactory.createParser(BaseSaxParserFactory.java:99)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1456)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1432)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:262)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:247)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
<jasper.version>5.6.1</jasper.version>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports: Getting JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715967/jasperreports-getting-jrruntimeexception-error-creating-sax-parser)

Comment: What version of JR are you using? Which libs are at cp?

Comment: @AlexK I have edited the question and added the version of jasper and also the dependency of xerces that I have added on pom.xml

Comment: @AlexK I have tried the post that you mentioned and added Xerces at the dependency of my project, but that did not work

Comment: Which libs are at cp?

Comment: @AlexK If you mean libraries on the build path of the project. JRE System Library and Maven Dependencies. Which in Maven dependency includes xsdlib-2013.6.1.jar and jasperreports-5.6.1.jar

Comment: This is nice post as well [Dealing with “Xerces hell” in Java/Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven)

Comment: @PetterFriberg This code is working in another similar project, but is not working on mine, I think this might be a configuration issue or something set on pom.xml.

Comment: I'm sorry but with information in question the best answer I can give you is that this seems like a "Xerces hell" problem, it's a famous problem it depends on different versions of different library's I bet you have this problem, try to clean up libraries used, check what jasper-reports distributes etc. and good luck (at least get some comfort that we all have gone through this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I knew the code was working fine and the issue was in the project setup. The pom.xml was fine and also the dependencys.

What I did in order to get this working was double click on tomcat server on Eclipse.

```
- Download xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar or any other version
- Click on "Open Launch Configuration"
- Go to the tab "Classpath"
- Click on Bootstrap Entries
- Add External JARs
- Select xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar or any version that you prefer.
```

Restart server and it should work.